# Create an array of objects with values from another object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an object looking like this

```
const item = {
  id: 123,
  type: 'book',
  sections: [{
    type: 'section',
    id: '456',
    index: 1,
    lessons: [{
      type: 'lesson',
      id: 789,
      index: 1
    },
    {
      type: 'lesson',
      id: 999,
      index: 2
    }
    ]
  }, {
    type: 'section',
    index: 2,
    id: 321,
    lessons: [{
      type: 'lesson',
      id: 444,
      index: 1
    },
    {
      type: 'lesson',
      id: 555,
      index: 2
    }
    ]
  }]
}
```

It should be assumed that there are more objects in sections and lessons array. I want to create a new object like this

```
result = [{
  section: 456,
  lessons: [789, 999]
}, {
  section: 321,
  lessons: [444, 555]
}]
```

I tried this loop but this just pushes indexes and not lesson's ids

```
let obj = {};
let sectionWithLessons = [];
let lessons = []

for (const i in item.sections) {
  obj = {
    sectionId: item.sections[i].id,
    lessonIds: item.sections[i].lessons.map((lesson) => {
      return lessons.push(lesson.id)
    }),
  };
  sectionWithLessons.push(obj);
}

console.log(sectionWithLessons);
```

How can i do this correctly and preferably with good performance in consideration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best/shortest thing is to use the map function, like:

```
const result2 = item.sections.map(({id, lessons}) => ({
  id, 
  lessons: lessons.map(({id: lessionId}) => lessionId)
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to convert the item sections to the desired result.

We'd convert each section into an object with a `section` value and `lessons` array.

To create the lessons array, we again use Array.map() to map each lesson to a lesson id.

```js
const item = { id: 123, type: 'book', sections: [{ type: 'section', id: '456', index: 1, lessons: [{ type: 'lesson', id: 789, index: 1 }, { type: 'lesson', id: 999, index: 2 } ] }, { type: 'section', index: 2, id: 321, lessons: [{ type: 'lesson', id: 444, index: 1 }, { type: 'lesson', id: 555, index: 2 } ] }] }

const result = item.sections.map(({ id, lessons }) => { 
    return ({ section: +id, lessons: lessons.map(({ id }) => id) })
});
console.log('Result:', result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: once small improvement here could be "variable shadowing" with having both sectionId and lessonId as `id` in the lessons.map callback, but the general idea of course is perfect 